# how to use following code recursively for different tables

Tags: javascript

```
Query(document).ready(function() {
  var trCount = $('.Firsttable tr').length;

  for (var i = 4; i <=4; i++) {

    var $td = $('.Firsttable tr:eq(2) td:eq(' + i + ')'),
      highest = 0,
      lowest = 9e99;

    for (var j = 1; j < trCount; j++) {
      $td = $td.add('.Firsttable tr:eq(' + j + ') td:eq(' + i + ')');
    }

    $td.each(function(i, el){
      var $el = $(el);
      if (i > 0) {
        var val = parseInt($el.text().replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10);
        if (val < lowest) {
            lowest = val;
            $td.removeClass('low');
            $el.addClass('low');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: just extract a function and use `.Firsttable tr'` as parameter, or just table classname `Firsttable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign ID attribute to each of your tables and write a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testTable(tableId) {
  var trCount = $('#'+ tableId +' tr').length;

  for (var i = 4; i <=4; i++) {

    var $td = $('#'+ tableId +' tr:eq(2) td:eq(' + i + ')'),
      highest = 0,
      lowest = 9e99;

    for (var j = 1; j < trCount; j++) {
      $td = $td.add('#'+ tableId +' tr:eq(' + j + ') td:eq(' + i + ')');
    }

    $td.each(function(i, el){
      var $el = $(el);
      if (i > 0) {
        var val = parseInt($el.text().replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10);
        if (val < lowest) {
            lowest = val;
            $td.removeClass('low');
            $el.addClass('low');
        }
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Now just call this function for every table by passing it's id,

```
<script type="text/javascript>
Query(document).ready(function() {
   testTable('table1');
   testTable('table2');
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps, thanks.